# How to get all the tasks between two dates for a project?

Tags: asana, asana-api

As a requirement, I want to get all the tasks created between any 2 dates(for a project). It does not matter whether these tasks got completed or not.

I looked at the Tasks [API](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query), which has a query section that talks about

> completed_since: Only return tasks that are either incomplete or that
>   have been completed since this time.
>    modified_since: Only return tasks
>   that have been modified since the given time.

I also looked at my Asana Dashboard which supports queries such as

[image]

Now this also does not let me query as per my requirement.

**Question** 
- What query/API payload do I need to run to get all the tasks between 2 dates (for a project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to query *just* for the tasks you want - however, you can query for all the tasks, and then just filter out the ones by their `created_at` value. So, e.g. `GET /projects/1234/tasks?opt_fields=name,completed_at,...`, then iterate over and just select the ones you want. Not very efficient, but the best that is currently possible.

Comment: sure yeah, thanks. I wanted to make sure I am not missing anything obvious